# Mocking a service that uses a context receiver Raise<BusinessError> using Mockito

Tags: kotlin, mockito, arrow-kt, kotlin-context-receivers

Source code available on Github: https://github.com/codependent/context-receiver-sample

Suppose you're testing a service `ServiceOne` that has a dependency on `ServiceTwo`.

`ServiceTwo` has a method `call()` with a context receiver of `Raise<BusinessError>`:

```
class ServiceOne(private val serviceTwo: ServiceTwo) {

    fun call(code: String): String {
        val result = either {
            val r = serviceTwo.call(code)
            r
        }

        return result.fold(
            { "-1" }){ it }
    }
}
```

```
class ServiceTwo {

    context(Raise<BusinessError>)
    fun call(id: String): String {
        return id
    }

}
```

```
sealed class BusinessError {
    object SomeError: BusinessError()
}
```

I'd like to mock the dependency on `ServiceTwo` using Mockito. In order to do so, when mocking I need to provide a context for its context receiver so I wrapped it with an either block:

```
class ServiceOneTests {


    @Test
    fun `should return the correct aggregation result`() {

        val serviceTwo = mock(ServiceTwo::class.java)
        val serviceOne = ServiceOne(serviceTwo)

        val result = either {
            `when`(serviceTwo.call("1")).thenReturn("1")

            val mockResult = serviceTwo.call("1")
            assertEquals("1", mockResult)

            serviceOne.call("1")
        }

        when(result){
            is Either.Left -> fail()
            is Either.Right -> assertEquals("1", result.value)
        }
    }

}
```

When executing the test, you can see that `mockResult`, which is `serviceTwo.call(code)` has been correctly mocked, having a "1" value.

However, this test ends up failing because `r` in `val r = serviceTwo.call(code)` in `serviceOne.call("1")` is null.

I suspect it must be because the context (`either {}`) used during the mock setup is different from the context established in `fun serviceOne.call()`, which has it's own `either {}` block.

How would you fix this so the mocked call doesn't return null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I suspect it must be because the context (either {}) used during the mock setup is different from the context established in fun serviceOne.call(), which has it's own either {} block.

> How would you fix this so the mocked call doesn't return null?

This is indeed because Mockito only mocks for the *exact* instance passed of `Either`, and you should use an argument matcher instead.

You can do this by casting to the underlying signature, and passing an explicit matcher for the context receiver.

```kotlin
val serviceTwo = mock(ServiceTwo::class.java)
val serviceOne = ServiceOne(serviceTwo)

`when`(serviceTwo::call.invoke(anyObject(), eq("1"))).thenReturn("1")
```

I had to define a helper to fix the *non-null* issue of Mockito, without brining in `mockito-kotlin`.

```kotlin
object MockitoHelper {
    fun <T> anyObject(): T {
        Mockito.any<T>()
        return uninitialized()
    }
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    fun <T> uninitialized(): T = null as T
}
```

Perhaps MockK will add support for this in the future, but I would recommend using interfaces and *stubs* instead of mocking. This would heavily simplify this pattern.